# How to remove an exact duplicate in an RPM db (same architecture)

Tags: rpm

On one system I have two exact same entries in the RPM DB:

```
# rpm -qa | fgrep gvfs-fuse
gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64
gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64
```

There is apparently nothing that will help:

```
# rpm -e --justdb --nodeps gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64
error: "gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64" specifies multiple packages:
  gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64
  gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64

# rpm --rebuilddb

# rpm -qa | fgrep gvfs-fuse
gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64
gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64
```

Is there a way to specify a package to remove (from db) more specifically in order to select one of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could remove both instances:

```
rpm -e --justdb --nodeps --allmatches gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64
```

and then reinstall the single rpm (which you would need to download in this case):

```
rpm -i --justdb --nodeps gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64.rpm
```

or if you don't mind that the files get reinstalled (and pre/post scripts executed again):

```
yum/zypper install gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1
```

Comment: The `rpm -i` accepts filename, so it would be `rpm -i --justdb --nodeps ./gvfs-fuse-1.40.0-1.1.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: @msuchy you are right. Elaborated a little on that.

Comment: Thanks, the "`--allmatches`" trick worked! (Reinstalled the package without `rpm`).